# Can't use .css to change display from none to block

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Here is my CSS:

```
#optionHotel{
    display:none;
}
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
function cb1(type){
    switch(type){
        case "hotel":
            alert("hotel");
            $("#optionHotel").css("display","block");
            break;
    }
}
```

Here is my Html:

```
<div id="optionHotel"> Some Element In here</div>
```

Start Script in 'Head Tag':

```
<?echo '
<script>window.onload = cb1("'.$orderType.'");</script>
'?>

<!--CSS-->
<link href="../../css/navigate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="../../css/reservation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Passing data from php to js is ok because I have checked In the switchcase

with alert() it's ok but I don't know why .css display to block doesn't work

please advice, Thank in advance

Comment: That's because DOM is not ready yet you are calling the function immediately, ie before your element is added to DOM. `window.onload = function(){ cb1("orderType") }`

Comment: $("#optionHotel").hide();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code:

```
<script>window.onload = cb1("'.$orderType.'");</script>
```

will call the `cb1()` function immediately and try to assign its result as the `window.onload` handler. You see the alert because the function does run, but because it runs immediately from inside the head of the document the document body has not yet been parsed so the script can't find your element.

You need to assign an actual function as the handler, where that function will be run onload and at that point will call `cb1()`:

```
<script>window.onload = function() { cb1("'.$orderType.'"); };</script>
```

Or, since you are using jQuery, and assuming you don't want to wait for images to load before calling your function, use a document ready handler:

```
<?echo '
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     cb1("'.$orderType.'");
  });
</script>
'?>
```

...or move the script to the end of the body and call your function directly:

```
<?echo '
<script>cb1("'.$orderType.'");</script>
'?>
```